# Unable to get a full name when i try to download a excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, c#-4.0, download

When i try to download a file with full name, its not getting download. but the in a parameter am sending the parameter as file name. file path is auto generated.

Downloading File name is : Update_4_Product (Showed in a screenshot)

Actual File name is : Update_4_Product Details.xlsx

[image]

This is my code

```
    private void DownloadUploadDataTemplate(string fileName)
    {
        string Outgoingfile = fileName + ".xlsx";
        string targetDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(XTP.Caching.AppSettingCache.GalleryFilePath) + @"\" + this.TenantCode + "\\Files" + @"\" + Outgoingfile;
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(targetDirectory);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            this.MessageLabel.Text = "File Not Found";
        }
    }
```

Can any one tell me what is the problem in my code.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the space in a file name.

```
str = str.Replace(" ", "_");
```

`Update_4_Product_Details.xlsx` instead of `Update_4_Product Details.xlsx`

its working as expected.